# How to reference multiple twigs with @Template()

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I plan to update the app that was running on Symfony 3.0.
I used to use @Template(), but when updating, I have to specify the root of the twig file in().
However, you need to change the reading of index.csv.twig and index.html.twig in _format.
Is there any good way?

Before (Symfony 3.0)

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/{_format}", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
     * @Method("GET")
     *  
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'html') {
        } elseif ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'csv') {
            $request->attributes->set('filename', 'post_article.csv');
        }
```

After (Symfony 3.4 <)

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/{_format}", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
     * @Method("GET")
     *  
     * @Template("AppBudle:Hq/Post:index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'html') {
        } elseif ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'csv') {
            $request->attributes->set('filename', 'post_article.csv');
        }
```

```
<button type="submit" class="btn">
       <i class="icon-download"></i>
       <a class="a_btn" href="{{ path('app_hq_post_index', {'_format': 'csv'}) }}"> output</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directly $this->render instead of @template

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_format}", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
 * @Method("GET")
 *  
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request, $_format)
{
    if ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'html') {
    } elseif ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'csv') {
        $request->attributes->set('filename', 'post_article.csv');
    }

    return $this->render(‘AppBudle:Hq/Post:index.´ . $_format .  ´.twig’);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I tried it, I got an error (Controller "PostController::indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$_format" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one). Am I forgetting to set something?

Comment: @scottie320 Check your defaults syntax carefully.  There is no particular reason why $_format would not be automatically set unless it does not have a default value.  And off-topic but twig paths like ‘AppBudle:Hq/Post:index' are also going away.  You will want to look up twig namespaces and use something like '@App/Hq/Post/index.html.twig''

Comment: @Cerad Really, I made a small mistake. Thanks you.