# Change parent format from @Template to render

Tags: php, symfony

When updating the app from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3.4, the handling of `_format` changed, so I would like to change @Template to render as shown in the post below.
However, because twig is changed in Parent format
Unable to specify twig file in return of BaseStaffController.php.
Is there any good way?

[How to reference multiple twigs with @Template()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66651098/how-to-reference-multiple-twigs-with-template/66652624?noredirect=1#comment117829075_66652624)

Controller

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/staff/", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
     * @Method("GET")
     *
     * @Template("@AppBundle/Hq/Analytics/staff.html.twig")
     */
    public function staffAction(Request $request)
    {
        return parent::staffAction($request);
    }
```

BaseStaffController

```php
    /**
     */
    public function staffAction(Request $request)
    {
        return array(
            'searchForm' => $searchForm->createView(),
            'pagination' => $pagination,
            'no' => $no
        );
    }
```

Comment: I would look at shifting away from the `@Template` annotation and instead using `$this->render` you can find a similar question on SO here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66651098/how-to-reference-multiple-twigs-with-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `parent::staffAction` is just returning the array of variables to be passed to the twig template then you can simply pass it along to the `render` method.

```
/**
 * @Route("/staff/", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
 * @Method("GET")
 *
 */
public function staffAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render("Hq/Analytics/staff.html.twig", parent::staffAction($request));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It was very helpful. Since I added some code, I will describe the code implemented in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ArleighHix's answer, it is a code that I could actually move.

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/staff/{_format}", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
     * @Method("GET")
     *
     */
    public function staffAction(Request $request, $_format)
    {
        return $this->render('@AppBundle/Hq/Analytics/staff.' . $_format . '.twig', parent::staffAction($request, $_format));
    }
```